# How to make UIView on top of all tab in UITabBarController

Tags: ios, swift, inheritance, uiview, uitabbarcontroller

To make uiview on top of all tabs of uitabbar controller .
[image]I planned to make one baseviewcontroller  named "uiView.swift" .In "uiView.swift" i added my uiview. After that i want to inherit each tab ViewController (say "resturent.swift") from that uiView.swift. So, in each tab of UITabBarController you will get that "uiView.swift" view resued.uiView.swift is connected to  ViewController in Storyboard that has button that show the view on button click  .Here is my "uiView.swift"

```
class uiView: UIViewController {
var menuView: UIView?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        menuView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: -200, width: 420, height: 200))
        menuView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        view.addSubview(menuView!)
    }
    @objc func MyBag(){

    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
    @IBAction func collectionmenuone(_ sender: Any) {
       menuView=UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 420, height: 200))
        menuView?.backgroundColor=UIColor.lightGray
        self.view.addSubview(menuView!)

        var btnbag = UIButton(type: .roundedRect)
        btnbag.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.MyBag), for: .touchUpInside)
        btnbag.frame = CGRect(x: 104, y:130 , width: 150, height: 60)
        btnbag.setTitle("Done", for: .normal)
        btnbag.backgroundColor=UIColor.green
        menuView?.addSubview(btnbag)

    }


}
```

how i can make possible reuse of view from "uiView.swift" in each tab of tabbar controller (i.e "resturent.swif")

```
class resturent:UICollectionViewController,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationItem.title="Seafood"
        collectionView?.backgroundColor=UIColor.white
        // view.backgroundColor=UIColor.redColor
        collectionView?.register(VideoCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cellid")
    }
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell=collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellid", for: indexPath)
        // cell.backgroundColor=UIColor.red
        return cell
    }
    /* override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexpath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
     let cell=collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath as IndexPath)

     return cell
     }*/
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let height=(view.frame.width - 16 - 16) * 9/16
        return  CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: height + 16 + 68)
    }
}
class VideoCell:UICollectionViewCell{
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupView()
    }
    let thumbnailImageView:UIImageView = {
        let imageView=UIImageView()
        imageView.backgroundColor=UIColor.blue
        imageView.image=UIImage(named: "food24")
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        imageView.clipsToBounds=true
        return imageView
    }()
    let userProfileImageView:UIImageView={
        let imageView=UIImageView()
        //imageView.backgroundColor=UIColor.green
        return imageView
    }()
    let separatorView:UIView = {
        let view = UIView ()
        view.backgroundColor=UIColor(red: 230/255, green: 230/255, blue: 230/255, alpha: 1)
        return view
    }()
    let titleLabel:UILabel={
        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=false
        label.text="Resturant name here"
        return label
    }()
    let subtitleTextView:UITextView = {
        let textView=UITextView()
        textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=false
        textView.textContainerInset=UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -4, 0, 0)
        textView.textColor=UIColor.lightGray
        textView.text = "SeaFood"
        return textView
    }()
    func setupView()  {
        //backgroundColor=UIColor.blue
        addSubview(thumbnailImageView)
        addSubview(separatorView)
        addSubview(userProfileImageView)
        addSubview(titleLabel)
        addSubview(subtitleTextView)
        addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "H:|-16-[v0]-16-|", view: thumbnailImageView)
        addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "H:|-16-[v0(44)]", view: userProfileImageView)
        //vertial constratints
        addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "V:|-16-[v0]-8-[v1(44)]-16-[v2(1)]|", view: thumbnailImageView,userProfileImageView,separatorView)
        addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "H:|[v0]|", view: separatorView)
        //top constraints
        addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: titleLabel, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem:thumbnailImageView , attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 8))
        //left constaints
        addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: titleLabel, attribute: .left, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: userProfileImageView, attribute: .right, multiplier: 1, constant: 8))
        //right constraint
        addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: titleLabel, attribute: .right, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: thumbnailImageView, attribute: .right, multiplier: 8, constant: 0))
        //height constraint
        addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: titleLabel, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .height, multiplier: 0, constant: 20))

        //top constraints
        addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: subtitleTextView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem:titleLabel , attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 4))
        //left constaints
        addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: subtitleTextView, attribute: .left, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: userProfileImageView, attribute: .right, multiplier: 1, constant: 8))
        //right constraint
        addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: subtitleTextView, attribute: .right, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: thumbnailImageView, attribute: .right, multiplier: 8, constant: 0))
        //height constraint
        addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: subtitleTextView, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .height, multiplier: 0, constant: 20))


        // addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "V:[v0(20)]", view: titleLabel)
        //  addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "H:|[v0]|", view: titleLabel)

    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
extension UIView{
    func addConstraintsWithFormat(format:String,view:UIView...){
        var viewDictionary=[String:UIView]()
        for (index,view) in view.enumerated(){
            let key="v\(index)"
            view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=false
            viewDictionary[key]=view
        }
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: format , options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: viewDictionary))
    }

}
```

uiView.swift is of type UIViewController and resturent.swif is of type UICollectionViewController.You can change the entry point of app from uiView.swift to login View controller(Viewcontroller.swift) to run app.How by inheritance i can reuse the view in uiView.swift ?you can download the project from this link .https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XSwOZcfvglB_7Zt_E8W8W3Dym3i1_lrB/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Are you making a popUp on your tabBarController and you want this popUp on above all the views currently displaying. Right?

Comment: popUp on your tabBarController on buton click

Comment: Can you highlight what are you currently doing when click on that button?

Comment: on uiView.swift when is button click just view is displayed in .i want to replicate this displayed view by  inheritance on all tabs of tabbar controller

Answer (score 0):

You should not add your menu View on any of your view. Instead of this you can direct add it on your window from AppDelegate.
Adding a view on window will place it above all the views that is been currently visible.

Comment: You can change the entry point of app from uiView.swift to login View controller(Viewcontroller.swift) to run app.

Comment: I want to have the uiview on all of my tabbar controller .The way i thought to have uiview on all of my tabbar controller is by inheriting the view from uiView.Swift to  all tab of tab bar controller .How i can accomplish this task?

Comment: Why you want to show on thing on every view controller?
As you can just show one on above all.

Comment: i just want popUp on button click on each tab of tabBarController